Сдвинуть ряд элементов правее что-бы первый оказался в центре
Как сдвинуть весь ряд правее что-бы синий div оказался в центре?
Только размеры всех элементов динамичные, просто сделать margin-left: 100px; не лучшее решение.


.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.centered {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="centered">Centered Div</div>
    <div class="item">Div 1</div>
    <div class="item">Div 2</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



